# How to make a column matrix top side down?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matrix

I have a dataframe of 3*1 dimensions. The dataframe looks like the following:

```
    weights
0   4
1   13
2   91
```

I want to make the dataframe upside down like the following:

```
    weights
0   91
1   13
2   4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked in the pandas dataframe docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the column to a numpy array and use an slice with a step of `-1` to reverse:

```
df['weights'] = df['weights'].to_numpy()[::-1]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   weights
0       91
1       13
2        4
```